Country Dropdown Auto-Select Causes 'No Options' Interference in Province Dropdown in React
I’m working on a React project with two dependent dropdowns:

A SelectCountry dropdown for selecting a country.
A SelectProvince dropdown for selecting a province, which dynamically loads its options based on the selected country.

Here’s the relevant code:
<SelectCountry
  name="country"
  value={paymentStepData.address.country}
  onChange={handleAddressUpdate}
/>

<SelectProvince
  name="province"
  selectedCountry={paymentStepData.address.country}
  value={paymentStepData.address.province}
  onChange={handleAddressUpdate}
/>

Problem:
When the country dropdown is auto-selected (e.g., via browser auto-fill or preloaded data), it interferes with the province dropdown as shown below:

Question:
How can I ensure the SelectProvince dropdown loads options properly when the country dropdown is auto-selected?
